# How does Eye tracking calibration helps the gaze estimation?

Tags: calibration, eye-tracking

I am asked to create calibration for the eye-tracking algorithm. However, I still don't really understand about how does the calibration helps in making our gaze estimation more accurate, as well as how calibration in eye-tracking actually works. I have read https://www.tobiidynavox.com/support-training/eye-tracker-calibration/, as well as https://developer.tobii.com/community/forums/topic/explain-calibration/, but I still don't fully understand it. I will appreciate if somebody can explain it to me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*In the answer below, I assume that you are referring to standard pupil-centre corneal-reflection video-oculography rather than any other form of eye tracking technology.*

In eye tracking, calibration is the process that transforms the coordinates of features located in a two dimensional still video frame of the eye into gaze coordinates (i.e. coordinates that are related to the world being observed). For example, let's say your eye tracker produces a 400 × 400 pixel image of the eye, and the subject is looking at a screen that is 1024 × 768 pixels in size, some distance in front of them. The calibration process needs to relate coordinates in the eye image to where the person is looking (i.e. gazing) at on the display screen. This process is not trivial: just because the pupil is centred in the eye image does not mean that the person is looking at the centre of the display in the world, for example. And the position of the pupil centre could move within the eye image even though the direction of gaze is held constant in the world. This is why we track the centre of the pupil *and* the corneal reflection, as the vector linking the two is robust to translation of the eye within the image that occurs in the absence of a gaze rotation.

A standard way to do this mapping is via relatively straightforward 2D non-linear regression: you move a target at known coordinates on the display and ask the participant to fixate steadily on each, while recording the location of the pupil centre and corneal reflection in the eye image. The calibration process will map the vector linking the pupil centre and the corneal reflection to the corresponding known gaze coordinates. This produces a regression solution that allows you to map intermediate locations to their interpolated gaze coordinates.

(An alternative, or supplementary, approach is model-based rather than regression-based, but let's not go there right now.)

So in essence, calibration doesn't *improve* gaze estimation, it *provides* gaze estimation. Without first doing a calibration, all you are doing is tracking the movements of features (the pupil and corneal reflection) within a relatively arbitrary image of the eye. Until calibration is carried out, you have no idea at that stage where that eye is actually pointing in the world.

Having said all that, this is not at all a coding-based question (or answer), so not actually sure that StackOverflow is the ideal venue to be asking this.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you for your good explanation. So, does that mean we store some values of the predicted gaze coordinates (based on how the user's eyes movement on calibration), to predict the gaze for other positions?

Comment: Its more like forming an equation (or more strictly, finding the optimal coefficients of that equation). The tracker can then feed any eye-image based coordinates into that equation to get an output representing estimated gaze coordinates. What information is available to you depends on your eyetracker manufacturer. SMI, for example, stored the raw image measures as well as the gaze data, so theoretically you could apply a different calibration method to the raw values. Most systems routinely record only the processed output (although that could itself be post-processed to correct errors).

Comment: Hi. Do you have any reference for the 2D non-linear regression method? I'm interested in being able to implement it.